# Opencv-python successfully installs but is missing from site-packages

Tags: installation, python

Bit of a strange one here - I've installed [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) via `pip install opencv-python`, the installation was successful and can be seen via `pip show opencv-python`, but when trying to import it into a project the package can't be found. On further investigation there isn't actually a opencv (cv2) folder in my site-packages, so I have no idea where it's retrieving the info. Has anyone ever come across this issue? I may be missing something totally obvious.

[image: Screenshot of pip output & site-packages folder]